# Get InvalidCastException with Glimpse, even though it's not installed. How do I fix this?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, azure, visual-studio-2013, glimpse

I had a Visual Studio 2012 project that I imported into Visual Studio 2013. I upgraded Entity Framework to version 6. I got the following error when I started the first time: **Unable to cast object of type 'Glimpse.Ado.AlternateType.GlimpseDbConnection' to type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection'.** Since this was a prototype app, I wasn't concerned about Glimpse, so I uninstalled it via NuGet, which removed the error and I carried on.

Now, I'm deploying to Azure websites and I keep getting that error!

- Glimpse is uninstalled.
- It works fine in release and debug locally.
- I tried putting `System.Data.Metadata.Edm.MetadataWorkspace.ClearCache();` in the Application_Start like [this](https://github.com/Glimpse/Glimpse/issues/130) says. (Even though I don't run queries in `Application_Start`

I suspect I have a caching problem on Azure, but I'm not sure. How do I get the Azure deployment to remove Glimpse like the local install has?

**Update:** "Fixed"it by deleting the azure website and recreating it. Would still love to hear how to do with this without going with the nuclear option.

Comment: Can you check if there's any glimpse file/dlls left in your project then delete it?

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug and is fixed in the release that will hopefully be going out tomorrow - see here for more details https://github.com/Glimpse/Glimpse/issues/540.

Comment: Thanks! Good to know. The problem in Glimpse was tangential to the question, though. Is it still a bug with Glimpse if I had uninstalled it? I think there's a caching issue with Azure. The problem would probably come up with another component too.

Comment: This fix has gone live.

Answer (score 1):

I also faced this error and later on found the resolution.

Issue was that I had MVC5 and EF6 based solution and i had imported Glimpse.mvc4 and Glimpse.ef5 packages and they were incompatible i think .

Once i upgraded to Glimpse.EF6 and Glimpse.MVC5 it started working fine.

Answer (score 1):

also had the same one, when I opted to remove Glimpse. 
you can prevent this by deleting the bin/ and obj/ folders from your project folder(s) as Glimpse is copied to your bin during debugging.